# Android popup form force closed

Tags: android, popup

I am working with android.I used to create a poupup form in xml which popups by clicking the button on the mail xml file.But It force closes the application.No error in my code. I cant find out my error.  Here is my code:

```
 imageButton2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


  public void onClick(View v) {
  View popUpView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popup, null); // inflating popup layout
  mpopup = new PopupWindow(popUpView, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true); //Creation of popup

  mpopup.showAtLocation(popUpView, Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);    // Displaying popup
  ImageButton Sub = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.submit);    
  Sub.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


    public void onClick(View v) {
          mpopup.dismiss();

    }
  }); 
 }
});
```

Comment: See logcat for helpful exception stacktrace and include it in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this:

```
 ImageButton Sub = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.submit);
```

With below:

```
 ImageButton Sub = (ImageButton) popUpView.findViewById(R.id.submit);
```

If i am not wrong then try out this.